# How to start learning Google Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: bigdata, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am studying computer engineering. And I am thinking of learning Google Cloud Dataflow.

So I wanted to ask is it good to learn Google Cloud Dataflow as a student in UG. Also I don't have much experience with Big Data or Hadoop.

If yes then how do I start learning it?

Comment: Maybe you can start with BigData so on 2-3 steps u will get in on Hadoop and after realize what they are, you can start Google Cloud Dataflow. On web there are  a lot of ebook , sure you can find

Comment: So is it better to first learn and have some expertise and knowledge of hadoop and MapReduce framework and then start with Cloud Dataflow?

Comment: Please note that the MapReduce model (roughly, a single huge SELECT followed by a single huge GROUP BY) is a trivial special case of what's offered by Dataflow (logical collections with operations on them, MapReduce being just one of the possible chains of operations). Can you clarify what are your learning goals - do you want to learn to process big data in practice, do you want to learn the relevant theoretical concepts/algorithms, or do you want to learn how bigdata processing frameworks work internally?

Comment: I want to learn how to process big data in practice and algorithms....and also to some extent how frameworks work.

Comment: https://twitter.com/felipehoffa/status/1133533732176969729

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We think Google Cloud Dataflow is an excellent place to start with Big Data analytics. We have built it from the ground up with simplicity and ease of use in mind.

Knowledge about other data processing technologies, such as MapReduce or Hadoop, would help a little to get you started, but they won't be hugely beneficial in learning or using Cloud Dataflow. With such a background, however, the benefits of the fully-managed service that the Cloud Dataflow provides would be more obvious.

A good place to start is our [main page](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/). You'll find all the relevant information there. Feel free to tag StackOverflow questions with `google-cloud-dataflow` with any questions that may come up.

That said, Cloud Dataflow service is currently in Alpha phase and access to it is limited to whitelisted users only. You may [apply to be whitelisted](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1Enq1EKFrujUx2NBBhc_KRGQL6qLvWlT_0Bub4rN3FSs/viewform).

Comment: If i start learning it, Do i need to have other resources apart from SDK ? I mean to run or test my codes do i need to spend money on Google's other cloud resources like Google Compute Engine.? Or i can first learn it like on offline bases and than after i have expertise i start applying it in actual scenarios?

Comment: You can run your code locally, just keep in mind that it may not perform well locally with a large data set.